# Capacitor: in-app navigation + custom URL redirect

Tags: auth0, capacitor

In my Capacitor app I am able to open a new window to facilitate a login (with Auth0).  Upon successful login it opens a Custom URL Scheme (which is registered in the Capacitor app).  It does prompt to say `Open In "my_app"?` in iOS, but selecting `Open` does send me back to the app.

I would like to do this same thing, but without opening a new browser window, and without the prompt.  Essentially without leaving the app.

My attempt at this was to set up my `allowNavigation` settings in `capacitor.config.json`, so that my auth provider is opened in-app.  This worked, but after a successful login it just hangs.  It doesn't prompt to open in the app or anything.

What sort of callback URL would be used for an in-app browser capacitor app?  Would a universal/custom URL scheme be needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that my problem here was the unexpected way to import the Capacitor Browser plugin.  Once I imported like the [Docs said](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/browser), the in-app browser window worked great.  I also removed these URLs from the `allowNavigation` setting (as in my case they are external and not controlled by us).

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';    
const { Browser } = Plugins;
...
await Browser.open({ url: 'http://capacitorjs.com/' });
```